# Swift crash on a line that only has a bracket

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I'm struggling to understand how a program can crash on a line with just a bracket. My open-source app, Steppy 2, is having this problem. I have been unable to replicate this myself, but multiple users have reported this problem and have sent crash reports. The crash occurs on the last bracket:

```
func loadBars() {
    let graphView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    graphView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.addSubview(graphView)
    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view":graphView]))
    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view]-(30)-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view":graphView]))

    let sortedDayKeys = Array(weekData.keys).sorted(<)

    for var day = 0; day < 7; day++ {
        let key = sortedDayKeys[day] as String
        let bar = STPYGraphBar(frame: CGRectZero)

        bar.dateKey = key
        bar.steps = weekData[key]
        bar.divider = divider
        bar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        graphView.addSubview(bar)
        graphView.bringSubviewToFront(bar)

        bar.createInnerView()

        addBarContraints(bar)
        graphView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[bar]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["bar":bar]))
        bars.append(bar)
    }
    graphView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[bar1][bar2(bar1)][bar3(bar1)][bar4(bar1)][bar5(bar1)][bar6(bar1)][bar7(bar1)]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["bar1":bars[0],"bar2":bars[1],"bar3":bars[2],"bar4":bars[3],"bar5":bars[4],"bar6":bars[5],"bar7":bars[6]]))
} //HERE
```

The crash information:

```
    Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  SwiftSteppy                    0x0000000100094b2c SwiftSteppy.STPYGraphView.loadBars (SwiftSteppy.STPYGraphView)() -> () (STPYGraphView.swift:108)
1  SwiftSteppy                    0x0000000100094100 SwiftSteppy.STPYGraphView.loadBars (SwiftSteppy.STPYGraphView)() -> () (STPYGraphView.swift)
2  SwiftSteppy                    0x000000010009100c SwiftSteppy.STPYGraphView.loadWithProgress (SwiftSteppy.STPYGraphView)(CoreGraphics.CGFloat) -> () (STPYGraphView.swift:32)
3  SwiftSteppy                    0x0000000100069a34 SwiftSteppy.STPYGraphViewController.loadMainScrollViewContent (SwiftSteppy.STPYGraphViewController)() -> () (STPYGraphViewController.swift:201)
4  SwiftSteppy                    0x0000000100067abc SwiftSteppy.STPYGraphViewController.loadDataInterface (SwiftSteppy.STPYGraphViewController)() -> () (STPYGraphViewController.swift:139)
5  SwiftSteppy                    0x00000001000713e0 SwiftSteppy.STPYGraphViewController.(loadData (SwiftSteppy.STPYGraphViewController) -> () -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #1) (STPYGraphViewController.swift:76)
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019866d3ac _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019866d36c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000198671980 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 932
9  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001878e1fa4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
10 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001878e004c __CFRunLoopRun + 1492
11 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018780d0a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
12 GraphicsServices               0x00000001909af5a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
13 UIKit                          0x000000018c13eaa4 UIApplicationMain + 1488
14 SwiftSteppy                    0x00000001000a5da8 main (STPYAppDelegate.swift:13)
15 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000198696a08 start + 4
```

The full crash information can be found [here](http://crashes.to/s/f70a5f711d9) and the code context [here](https://github.com/ATFinke-Productions/Steppy-2/blob/master/Shared/Graph/STPYGraphView.swift#L108) with the line where the crash occurs highlighted.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code and the symbolicated crash log. Links tend to rot so you need to include the relevant info in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, swift crash reports don't indicate the exact line the app crashed on, unlike objective-c apps. This means some line in the method triggered the crash, not the final bracket.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to where you found this information?

Comment: @user2844801 link is redirecting. Do you have a other source 
   
for this devforums.apple.com/message/1106933

Comment: @user2844801 Do you know the exact reason for not showing the crash line in swift

Comment: @karthikPrabhuAlagu, do you have fresh link? Your link opens the root of apple developer forums