# Crash report indicating crash on line 0?

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports

Can anyone help demystify this crash report?

There's no exception name or reason, and the backtrace shows the crash happening on line 0 of the file that contains the `init` method that crashed.  *What?*

```
Incident Identifier: TODO
CrashReporter Key:   TODO
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:         AppName [1112]
Path:            /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2632C5D7-6A07-4002-A27B-D547E9A7345C/AppName.app/AppName
Identifier:      com.app.name
Version:         67
Code Type:       ARM-64
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2015-06-26 18:20:18 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 8.3 (12F70)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGTRAP
Exception Codes: TRAP_BRKPT at 0x10008c370
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception '', reason: ''
```

The first couple symbolicated lines of the crashed thread:

```
0    AppName 0x000000010008c370 init (article, $metatype) (ArticleImageProvider.swift:0)
1    AppName 0x000000010006b0c4 shareArticleActivityViewController (article, track) (BasicArticleSharingController.swift:28)
2    AppName 0x0000000100063198 sharePressed () (DetailsViewController.swift:202)
3    AppName 0x00000001000600c8 sharePressed () (DetailsViewController.swift:200)
4    AppName 0x00000001000bfa8c sharePressed () (ContentNavView.swift:108)
5    AppName 0x000000010022f4b4 __55-[ASControlNode sendActionsForControlEvents:withEvent:]_block_invoke (ASControlNode.m:360)
6    AppName 0x000000010022f21c -[ASControlNode sendActionsForControlEvents:withEvent:] (ASControlNode.m:381)
7    AppName 0x000000010022e5b8 -[ASControlNode touchesEnded:withEvent:] (ASControlNode.m:191)
8    AppName 0x000000010026185c -[_ASDisplayView touchesEnded:withEvent:] (_ASDisplayView.mm:173)
9    UIKit 0x0000000187613d8c forwardTouchMethod + 260
10    UIKit 0x00000001874b0a2c -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 696
11    UIKit 0x00000001874a9f68 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 680
12    UIKit 0x000000018747d18c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 260
13    UIKit 0x000000018771e324 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 15420
14    UIKit 0x000000018747b6a0 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1712
```

---

Here's some code:

```
// Where I attach the action to my button in ContentNavView
    shareButton.addTarget(self, action: "sharePressed", forControlEvents: ASControlNodeEvent.TouchUpInside)

/* snip */

// The implementation of ContentNavView#sharePressed()
func sharePressed() {
    delegate.sharePressed()
}
```

```
// The implementation of DetailsViewController#sharePressed()
func sharePressed() {
    if let cell = currentCell {
        let activityViewController = BasicArticleSharingController.shareArticleActivityViewController(cell.article)

        self.view.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

```
// The implementation of BasicArticleSharingController#shareArticleActivityViewController(::) up to the initializer
class func shareArticleActivityViewController(article: Article, track: Bool = true) -> UIActivityViewController {
    var article = CoreDataManager.sharedManager.managedObjectContextForCurrentThread().objectWithID(article.objectID) as! Article

    let activities = [
        ArticleImageProvider(article: article), // Crash when calling this init?
        ArticleLinkProvider(article: article)
    ]

    /* snip */
}
```

```
// Implementation of the init that's crashing.  Apparently Swift only reports the class that crashes, not the line that crashes, so here's the implementation that I thought wasn't relevant.
final public class ArticleImageProvider: UIActivityItemProvider {

    let articleObjectID: NSManagedObjectID

    init(article: Article) {
        self.articleObjectID = article.objectID

        let article: Article = CoreDataManager.sharedManager.managedObjectContextForCurrentThread().objectWithID(article.objectID) as! Article

        let thumbnailCut = article.headlineImage?.cutWithShape(.Landscape)

        if let path = thumbnailCut?.localURL?.path {
            if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path) {
                super.init(placeholderItem: image)
            }
            else {
                super.init(placeholderItem: UIImage())
            }
        } else {
            super.init(placeholderItem: UIImage())
        }
    }

    /* snip */
}
```

Comment: did you update xcode? try removing the cache files

Comment: Actually it seems to me that you know quite a lot about where in your code to look for the problem. You don't show _us_ any code, though, so it's hard to see what you're asking. Aside from "what?" there doesn't seem to be any question anyway.

Comment: @jycr753 This crash report was symbolicated by Crittercism.  Xcode wouldn't help here, anyway, I think.

Comment: @matt The question is if anyone could help demystify the crash report.  I've added the implementations alluded to in the backtrace.

Comment: But you don't say what is mystifying about it, so what's to demystify. You're crashing in ArticleImageProvider, it appears. But you haven't shown it...

Comment: @matt The crash is on line 0, which doesn't exist, as far as I can tell, and the exception name and reason are empty strings.  In any event, I added the implementation for the method that has the crash in it because of what the answer in this question says: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778177/swift-crash-on-a-line-that-only-has-a-bracket

Comment: @matt I'd appreciate any insight, now that I've provided everything you've asked for.

Comment: You have a forced cast. How do you know it can't crash?

Comment: @matt The object's ID is gotten from an object that matches the type that I'm casting to, in both cases, which is to say I'm getting an object ID from an `Article` and casting to an `Article`.  Is this unsafe?

Comment: A forced cast is _always_ unsafe. `objectWithID` can return anything. It might be some other kind of object. It might be `nil`. Any time you use an exclamation mark in your code, _you can crash_. That's what the exclamation mark _means_. I'm not saying this _is_ the cause, but I am certainly saying that your code is begging to crash.

Comment: Also your whole coda (the sequence of different `super.init` calls) is poorly constructed. It's not causing the crash, but it's not how I'd write it. I'd start with a UIImage `var`, set it depending on the conditions, and call `super` _once_.

Comment: @matt Thanks for looking.  Can you see anything here that might definitely cause a crash?  No one in-house is experiencing anything like what our users are reporting.

Comment: I've said. The exclamation mark might definitely cause a crash. I don't see what you want from me (or from Stack Overflow). You are the one who has elected to use a bad form of crash reporting and symbolication (Crittercism). It isn't giving you all the information you're entitled to. You're putting on a blindfold and then complaining that you can't see.

Comment: Not really, no.  Apple is providing zero crash reports, and crashing in Xcode while testing reports the same information as Crittercism.  Your personal ideas of how good or bad Crittercism may be and how that influenced your response notwithstanding, your "help" and snark have reinforced the idea that Stack Overflow as a community is going down the drain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, a few things I learned here:

1. `objectWithID:` returns `NSManagedObject`.  That's it.  There's no guarantee that the object you're sending that message to will return an object of the same type as the receiver, so testing the returned object is the safest way to handle this.  As a corollary to that, scoping `NSFetchRequest`s to reduce or eliminate threading issues with managed objects is a paramount concern and will eliminate this problem altogether.
2. There are simply fewer signal traps in compiled Swift code, so getting a crash report from Apple or Crittercism (through `NSThread#callStackSymbols` or some other API) will always return the same junk I'm showing here.  The best you can do is infer the lexical scope that's likely the cause of the crash and comb the code for any possible errors.  We're stuck having to do this until Swift matures.
3. Use implicitly unwrapped optionals sparingly.

Comment: Another solution - the one I've decided reluctantly to adopt - is to go back to coding mostly in Objective C until Swift matures.